# How to set domain of pair variable in CSP in Sicstus Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, meta-predicate

I'm using Sicstus Prolog, and I'm trying to solve the Domino Puzzle.

I have a list with triplets, which I need to set the domain of. I know how to set the domain of a single variable, or a list of single variables, but how can I do it if my list has triplets, and each of the elements of the triples has a different domain?

```
DV = [R1-C1-D1, R2-C2-D2, ... , R15-C15-D15]
```

What I want to do is this:

```
domain(R1, 1, 4)
domain(C1, 1, 4)
domain(D1, 0, 1)
domain(R2, 1, 4)
domain(C2, 1, 4)
domain(D2, 0, 1)
....
domain(R15, 1, 4)
domain(C15, 1, 4)
domain(D15, 0, 1)
```

How can I do this without having to explicitly state each of the variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Describe the domains for one element:

```
eldoms(R-C-D) :-
   domain(R, 1, 4),
   domain(C, 1, 4),
   domain(D, 0, 1).
```

And:

```
..., maplist(eldoms, RCDs), ...
```

using [`library(maplist)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/maplist.pl).

Alternatively, using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/lambda.pl):

```
..., maplist(
        \ (R-C-D) ^ (  domain(R, 1, 4),
                       domain(C, 1, 4),
                       domain(D, 0, 1) ), RCDs), ...
```

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to implement The Domino Puzzle in (sicstus) prolog (using only constraint logic). I've found a pretty detailed guide explaining the logic, but I'm having trouble actually implementing it. I was wondering if you could help me out, please?